# commutativity of cycle permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

How is the following true, (given two cycle permutations a and b) $(a)^{-1} (b)^{-1} = ((b)(a))^{-1}$ where b and a contain one of the same elements. isn't it only disjoint cycles that are commutative?

Comment: This is not about commutativity as commutativity is $(a)(b)=(b)(a)$ whithout the inverse signs. Here we have :$(b)(a)(a)^{-1}(b)^{-1}=(b)((a)(a)^{-1})(b)^{-1}=(b)(b)^{-1}=e$ also, $(a)^{-1}(b)^{-1}(b)(a)=(a)^{-1}((b)^{-1}(b))(a)=(a)^{-1}a=(a)=e$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to note:

(1) $a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}$ is not showing commutativity of two elements.
(Commutativity would be $a^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.)

(2) Sometimes nondisjoint cycles commute.  For instance $(12345)(13524)=(13524)(12345)$

Comment: sorry sir, but the question is asking what happen if b and a contain one of the same element?